# Auth Google Analytics PHP API

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have tried the official [HelloAnalytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#helloanalyticsphp) tutorial however it doesn't work.

I am recieveing this error:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials' not found"

**My Code:**

```
  // Creates and returns the Analytics service object.

  // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

  // Use the developers console and replace the values with your
  // service account email, and relative location of your key file.
  $service_account_email = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
   $key_file_location = 'key_anyl.p12';

 // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("HelloAnalytics");
   $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

 // Read the generated client_secrets.p12 key.
  $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
  $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_email,
  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
  $key
   );
 $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
   if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
   $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
  }
```

**Update:**

after adding the suggested V1-master branch I am now getting the following error

> Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error
>   calling GET googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts: (403)
>   User does not have any Google Analytics account.'

Comment: if your not using composer make sure you downloaded the v1-master branch https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master

Comment: thx i have tried this version but now i get this error Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts: (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account.'

Comment: Check the answer I have just added. this is getting to long for comments.

Comment: Welcome to stack I have edited your question a little to show you how you can format questions for better reading of future users who may be helped by your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem nr 1:

if your not using composer make sure you downloaded the v1-master branch  – [Link](http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master)

Problem nr 2:

> (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account.

You are using a service account by default a service account does not have access to any google analytics accounts.   You need to take the service account email address from Google Developers console and add it as a user at the ACCOUNT level it must be the ACCOUNT level in the Google Analytics website under the admin section.

Comment: thx for the help. you mean @developer.gserviceaccount.com , how can i get it?

Comment: Its the one that you created along with your .p12 file.   on Google Developers console.   in this section of your tutorial https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#clientId

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you need to add the base directory of the library in the php 'include_path'.

Try putting this line of code before the require_once

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'vendor/google/src' );
```

Comment: i don't have src in vendor/google/ but i tried  set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'vendor/google/auth/src' ); and the error is the same